# Export SCHEMAS and TABLES at the same time

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

My task is export schemas sch1, sch2

Also need to export tablespaces ts88, ts89 from schema sch3

How can I do it as one operation?
Because, if I run different operations :

```
DIRECTORY=dir
ESTIMATE_ONLY=Y
LOGFILE=file.log
SCHEMAS=sch1, sch2
PARALLEL=4
```

and

```
DIRECTORY=dir
ESTIMATE_ONLY=Y
LOGFILE=file.log
TABLES=sch3.ts88, sch3.ts89
PARALLEL=4
```

it work fine.

But when I try something like this :

```
DIRECTORY=dir
ESTIMATE_ONLY=Y
LOGFILE=file.log
SCHEMAS=sch1, sch2
TABLES=sch3.ts88, sch3.ts89
PARALLEL=4
```

I got UDE-00010: multiple job modes requested, schema and tables.

As I understood It not possible to run export this way with schemas and tables.

Can I run it with INCLUDE or any other way?
Or it must be 2 different operations?

Comment: Where in this INCLUDE see that this tables are from sch3?
What if the same tables also in sch1 or sch2?

Comment: Sorry I read your question wrong ,you're right you can't mix export of full schemas and filtering tables from different schema.I'm afraid there is no option but to run two operations as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. Already read all documentations and made the same conclusion.